# Is solr cloud applicable for use case where indexing is offline?

Tags: performance, solr, lucene, solr4, solrcloud

Solr cloud seems to be the suggested method to scale solr in future. I understand that legacy scaling methods (like master slave and replication) still exists. My use case with solr does not have to be near real time (NRT). It is fine if the newly indexed data is visible for searchers after about 1 day.

In the master slave ([legacy](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Legacy+Scaling+and+Distribution) scaling), I could replicate it once a day. In Solr cloud do i have an option like this?

Also i don't want the indexing to impact the searcher performance during index time. Is there a way to isolate the indexer from searcher shards in solr cloud?

Answer (score 0):

You could skip SolrCloud and just index on a dedicate separate collection.

Then, you bring the new content to each machine individually and do a [Core Swap](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/CoreAdmin+API#CoreAdminAPI-SWAP).

Or similar thing using [Aliases](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API) to point to the newest core/collection. Which also allows you to segment old content and new content into different collections and search them together.

Answer (score 0):

I also used collection aliases in such cases. You can build your index once a day and when it is ready you simply change the alias. I'll give an example

At very begining you create index called: index_2014_12_01. This index is aliased by index_2014_12_01. The next day you build index_2014_12_02 and changing the alias now to point index_2014_12_02 instead of index_2014_12_01.